# Finding javafx jar file for windows

Tags: java, jar, javafx

Does anyone know where I can find the jar file for the `javafx` package for windows? I can only find zip files and exe files. Can someone answer with a link to download the package?

Comment: Have you tried search.maven.org?  There's a bunch of projects with "javafx" in the name.  Not sure which one matches your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX comes together with the latest JDK/ JRE from Oracle.

Comment: Where can you downlod the jar file?

Comment: Not true in Java 11 and later

Comment: @ncmathsadist yes, this changed again with Java 11.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first install the javafx_sdk-2_0_1-windows-i586.exe That will install JavaFx 2 sdk on your machine at by defualt C drive. You can get jfxrt.jar at following location
C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0\lib\jfxrt.jar

you have to refer this in classpath of your project.

Comment: The separate download (currently v2.2.7) is only for Java SE 6, which has reached End Of Life. JavaFX is co-bundled with the latest JDK/ JRE  from Oracle for Java SE 7.

Comment: Yes.. I am having version 2.0 and using it since long. These are just sample paths that I had given in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Since java 1.7 the javafx is embedded in JRE/JDK, you can find the jfxrt.jar

under directory C:\Program Files\Java[jdk1.8.0_25]\jre\lib\ext (conform to your jdk location)

Note, if you are using java 1.6 or below, you will not find it.

Answer (score 1):

It comes with JRE - Currently, I have 1.8
In Windows - 
 1. Visit this path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\lib
 2. Add "jfxswt.jar" to libraries

Make sure also you have the same JRE

[Eclipse - Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lq2C.png)